# Angular 5 ngsubmit not working inside modal popup window for add delete

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-submit

I am creating new angular 2 application in which i have created the one component(html and ts) files respectively.

in which i have displayed the list and after list model for editing and adding records.

now when I am submiting form only two fields are passing correct data to component. Rest of the fields went null. Also when i try to edit record then nothing happen. Can anyone help me to resolve issue.

Here is my model.

```
export interface ProductCategory{
    categoryId: number;
    productType: string;
    description : string;
    updatedBy: Date;
    isActive: boolean;  
    lastUpdatedDate: Date;
}
```

Here is my component html.

```
<div class="container">



    <div class="row">
        <div class='panel panel-primary'>
            <div class='panel-heading'>
              Category Management
            </div>
            <div class='panel-body'>
              <div class='table-responsive'>
                <div style="padding-bottom:10px"><button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addproductcategory()">Add</button></div>
                <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" *ngIf="indLoading"><img src="../../images/loading.gif" width="32" height="32" /> Loading...</div>
                <div *ngIf='ProductCategories && ProductCategories.length==0' class="alert alert-info" role="alert">No record found!</div>




              <table id="mytable" class="table table-bordred table-striped">

                   <thead>

                   <th><input type="checkbox" id="checkall" /></th>
                   <th>ProductType</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                     <th>UpdatedBy</th>
                     <th>IsActive</th>
                     <th>LastUpdatedDate</th>

                      <th>Edit</th>

                       <th>Delete</th>
                   </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        <tr *ngFor="let ProductCategory of ProductCategories">
                      <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkthis" /></td>
                      <td>{{ProductCategory.productType}}</td>
                      <td>{{ ProductCategory.description }}</td>
                      <td>{{ ProductCategory.updatedBy }}</td>
                      <td>{{ ProductCategory.isActive }}</td>
                      <td>{{ ProductCategory.lastUpdatedDate   }}</td>
                      <td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip"  (click)="editproductcategory(ProductCategory.categoryId)" title="Edit"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></p></td>
                      <td><p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" (click)="deleteProductCategory(ProductCategory.categoryId)" title="Delete"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></p></td>
                      </tr>

                    </tbody>

              </table>

              <div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="msg" role="alert" class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
            {{msg}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>

 </div>

 <bs-modal #modal>
    <form novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="ProdCateForm">
      <bs-modal-header [showDismiss]="true">
        <h4 class="modal-title">{{modalTitle}}</h4>
      </bs-modal-header>
      <bs-modal-body>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div>
            <span>ProductType</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ProductType" formControlName="producttype"> 
          </div>
          <div>
            <span>Description</span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" formControlName="description">
          </div>
          <div>
                <span>UpdatedBy</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="UpdatedBy" formcontrolName="updatedBy">
          </div>

          <div>
                <span>Updated date</span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control"  ngbDatepicker placeholder="LastUpdatedDate" formcontrolName="lastUpdatedDate">
          </div>

          <div>
                <span>isActive</span>
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" formcontrolName="isActive">
          </div>

        </div>
      </bs-modal-body>
      <bs-modal-footer>
        <div>
          <a class="btn btn-default" (click)="modal.dismiss()">Cancel</a>
          <button type="submit" [disabled]="ProdCateForm.invalid" class="btn btn-primary" >{{modalBtnTitle}}</button>
        </div>
      </bs-modal-footer>
    </form>
  </bs-modal>
```

Here is my Component ts code.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { RepositoryService } from '../shared/services/repository.service';
import { ProductCategory } from '../_interfaces/ProductCategory.model';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { DBOperation } from '../shared/services/enum';
import { BsModalComponent } from 'ng2-bs3-modal';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.css']
})
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('modal') modal: BsModalComponent; 


  public ProductCategories: ProductCategory[];
  indLoading: boolean = false;  
//   productcategoryfrm: FormGroup;  

ProdCateForm: FormGroup;  
  dbops: DBOperation;  
  modalTitle: string;  
  modalBtnTitle: string; 
  msg: string;   
  ProductCategory: ProductCategory;  
   constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private repository: RepositoryService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.ProdCateForm = this.fb.group({  
      producttype: [''],  
      description: [''] ,
      updatedBy: [''],  
      lastUpdatedDate: [null],  
      isActive: [''],
  });  
    this.getAllProductCategory();
  }

  public getAllProductCategory()
  {
    let apiAddress: string = "api/prodCategory";
    this.repository.getData(apiAddress)
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.ProductCategories = res as ProductCategory[];

       this.indLoading = false; 
     console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
    //this.repository.getData(apiAddress).subscribe(result => { this.ProductCategories =result as ProductCategory[]
    });
  } 


  addproductcategory() {  
    this.dbops = DBOperation.create;  
    this.SetControlsState(true);  
    this.modalTitle = "Add New Product Category";  
    this.modalBtnTitle = "Add";  
    this.ProdCateForm.reset();  
    this.modal.open();
}  

editproductcategory(categoryId: number) {
    console.log(categoryId);
  this.dbops = DBOperation.update;
  this.SetControlsState(true);
  this.modalTitle = "Edit User";
  this.modalBtnTitle = "Update";
  //this.ProductCategory = this.ProductCategories.filter(x => x.categoryId == id)[0];

  let apiAddress: string = "api/prodCategory/ ${categoryId} ";
  this.repository.getData(apiAddress)
  .subscribe(res => {
    this.ProductCategory = res as ProductCategory;

     this.indLoading = false; 
   console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
  //this.repository.getData(apiAddress).subscribe(result => { this.ProductCategories =result as ProductCategory[]
  });


  this.ProdCateForm.setValue(this.ProductCategory);
  this.modal.open();
}

onSubmit() {

  this.msg = "";  
  let apiAddress: string ;
  switch (this.dbops) {  
      case DBOperation.create:      
      apiAddress= "api/prodCategory/Create";
     console.log( this.ProdCateForm.value);
      this.repository.create(apiAddress, this.ProdCateForm.value).subscribe(data => {  

        if (data == 1) //Success    
              {  
                  console.log(data);
                  this.msg = "Data successfully added.";  
                  this.getAllProductCategory();  
              } else { 
                console.log(data); 
                  this.msg = "There is some issue in saving records, please contact to system administrator!"  
              }  
              this.modal.dismiss();  
          }, error => {  
              this.msg = error;  
          });  
          break;  
      case DBOperation.update:  
      apiAddress= "api/prodCategory/Put";
          this.repository.update(apiAddress,  this.ProdCateForm.value).subscribe(data => {  
              if (data == 1) //Success    
              {  
                  this.msg = "Data successfully updated.";  
                  this.getAllProductCategory();  
              } else {  
                  this.msg = "There is some issue in saving records, please contact to system administrator!"  
              }  
              this.modal.dismiss();  
          }, error => {  
              this.msg = error;  
          });  
          break;  
      case DBOperation.delete: 
      //apiAddress= "api/prodCategory/Delete";

      apiAddress= "api/owner/";//+  this.productcategoryfrm.AlbumId;
          this.repository.delete(apiAddress).subscribe(data => {  
              if (data == 1) //Success    
              {  
                  this.msg = "Data successfully deleted.";  
                  this.getAllProductCategory();  
              } else {  
                  this.msg = "There is some issue in saving records, please contact to system administrator!"  
              }  
              this.modal.dismiss();  
          }, error => {  
              this.msg = error;  
          });  
          break;  
  }  
} 

SetControlsState(isEnable: boolean) {  
  isEnable ? this.ProdCateForm.enable() : this.ProdCateForm.disable();  
}  
}
```

nothing is working except list.

below is my json when loading data to first time.

```
[{"categoryId":1,"productType":"It product","description":"All product Related to IT","updatedBy":"It user2","isActive":true,"lastUpdatedDate":"2018-07-18T19:47:20.817"},{"categoryId":2,"productType":"Home product","description":"All product Related to Home","updatedBy":"Home user","isActive":true,"lastUpdatedDate":"2018-07-14T23:31:55.09"},{"categoryId":10002,"productType":"Sport user","description":"Sport user Category","updatedBy":"Sport user","isActive":true,"lastUpdatedDate":"2018-07-19T18:55:02"},{"categoryId":10005,"productType":"Caar User","description":"Caar User Category","updatedBy":"Caar User","isActive":true,"lastUpdatedDate":"2018-07-19T18:55:02"}]
```

Please help me to resolve this issues.

Thanks in Advance.
Omkar.

Comment: No Comment/reply yet?